# What wall anchors should I use to hang a frame on plastered breeze block?

Tags: walls, hanging

I have a fairly hefty wooden calendar 2.5kg (5.5lbs). It has two hanging key slots in the back to hang it from. The keys are about 5mm wide on the narrow bit with a depth of 10mm.

I want to hang on my wall which is breeze block with about 15mm plasterboard over it.

I'm not useless with DIY and will be able to hang it myself, but I just don't know what hardware I need to put in the wall with the mix of materials etc...

Hope you will be able to help/advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a light enough object that standard hollow-wall anchors (plastic plugs) should work fine. They'll do the job whether or not you hit a portion of the breeze block behind the wallboard.

- Carefully locate the mounting points on the wall.
- Drill for your plugs--usually 1/4" or 5/16". Note that hitting the block will severely dull your bit. You may want to use masonry bits for that part.
- Insert the plugs and then insert appropriately sized screws.